# Python IDLE giving startup error

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, startup, python-idle

I have just installed kivy in python 2.7.11. After installing it, whenever i try to open IDLE, it is giving subprocess startup error.
Actually i installed kivy on my windows 7 PC through command prompt. After installation, I copied programs of kivy from my android tab to run them on my pc. When I tried to open them, IDLE doesn't respond for some time and after some time it gives startup error. Since then IDLE is not starting .
But it is quite strange that, on running python builtin module, there is no error.
I had reinstalled python but still there is no change.

Comment: Please post the full error output (and in general do so when posting the question, nobody can help without information about what's wrong).

Comment: Run IDLE from console with `python -m idlelib.idle` and you may get more information.  Be more specific as to how you tried to start IDLE, and what 'file name' you changed.  What is operating system?

Comment: Terry Jan, thanks for help. The IDLE is running via console, but still, not starting directly. Any solution???

Answer (score 0):

reason for subprocess startup error can be a new python file that you have created recently with the same name as same existing libraries or module name

> e.g. 're.py','os.py' etc

beacuse re,os are the predefined libraries

just go and find the file and rename it
hope so it will be resolved